# Unable to Publish using Frontpage 2003 in FTP mode through a VPN through another VPN

Tags: ftp, windows-vista, publish, vpn, frontpage

When I'm working from home I need to connect to a proprietary VPN to access the main corporate network and then another Cisco AnyConnect VPN to connect through the main corporate network to the web servers...  I have no problem connecting via Putty SSH or DOS/CommandLine FTP but FrontPage 2003 is unable to connect to the web server (using FTP).  I've looked in a lot of places and just can't seem to find anyone asking a question like this anywhere. Help!

Other things that may help you help me:

I CAN connect to the FTP server using the Notepad++ FTP mode and I can't connect using WinSCP

I need to use a proxy server to connect to normal websites when I'm on the corporate network, I have disabled this proxy on the off chance, but no luck.

Yes, I've tried enabling passive FTP and it didn't help

The port is 21 and the connection is FTP (not SFTP or whatever)

Yes, I know I can just use Command Line FTP to publish my files after editing them in Frontpage... its just really inconvenient.

I'm running Vista and using it's internal Firewall <s>but I cannot disable it for troubleshooting, so if that's the problem I guess I'm SOL</s> but I tried disabling it and it didn't help

I do not have this problem when I am actually on the corporate network.

Chrome works, Firefox Works, IE doesn't work, Explorer doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A big thanks to [Marc Reside](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1429/marc-reside) for some offline help on this one!

It took me a few days to figure this out but here's the solution:

Programs that rely on the settings you edit using the "Internet Options" dialog (IE, Windows Explorer and FrontPage) were the problem.  It turns out that LAN Settings and VPN settings are separate. So all I had to do was check "Automatically Detect Settings" for my VPN settings and it worked fine. (Duh!)

All the programs that were working were apparently using their own internal settings instead of the connection specific settings and were fine.